# Passing context to ajax/success function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, callback, scope

I call this function on a form element, and based on what the json object contains, change the background of a form element. Essentially a simplified validation - but I don't wanna use jQuery's bloated validation plugins.

```
IV.validSimple
(
    { 
        obj: '#email', 
        event: 'blur', 
        check: 'emailexists' 
    }
);
```

The problem is (the closure context/scope drives me mad :), how can I pass the d variable (object) to the success callback (_IV.bool) in the code below.

```
var IV = 
{
    urlBase: '/oink/ajax/',

    validSimple: function(d)
    {
        var _IV = this;

        $(d.obj).bind(d.event, function()
        {
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: _IV.urlBase + d.check + '?' + $(d.obj).val(),
                async: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: _IV.bool,
            });
        }
        );
    },

    bool: function(data)
    {
        if (data.ok == 1)
            $(obj).css('backgroundColor','#c5e8c5');
        else
        {
            $(obj).css('backgroundColor','#f7c7c7').focus();
        }
    } //function
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you  could set the `context` option:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _IV.urlBase + d.check + '?' + $(d.obj).val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    context: d.obj, // or  context: d , don't know which one you want
    success: _IV.bool,
});
```

and use `$(this)` inside `bool` instead of `$(obj)`.

Use whatever way seems more logical to you.

Answer (score 3):

just do

```
...
success: function(data) {
    _IV.bool(data, d)
}
...
```

in your query initialization code and redefine `bool` this way:

```
...
bool: function(data, d) {
...
```

Comment: Ah darn, it's too early in the morning here :DD. Thanks.